# Python/Heroku Facebook app infinite loop in my local environment

Tags: facebook, authentication, heroku, localhost, infinite-loop

So I followed all the steps to create a Facebook/Heroku app, and it's working fine at
http://lokalt.herokuapp.com/

I then set-up a local environment but it doesn't work that well, it basically infinite loops on login and never quite seems to be able to get the access token into the python app (get_token() returns None it seems), I'm pretty sure I'm getting a response from the facebook server though as I used console.log() and got a response object.

I don't have SSL working locally, but most other things should work.

Comment: Can you paste some of your code? Without seeing any code it's hard to help.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just wanted to try it out, and I am afraid I dropped it after it didn't work out-of-the-box.